# How do I take the derivative of $-f \nabla^2(f)$ with respect to $f$?

Tags: derivatives

How do I perform the derivative of

$$-f\nabla^2f$$ with respect to $f$, i.e.

$$\frac{\delta(-f\nabla^2f)}{\delta f}~?$$

The answer is supposedly $-2\nabla^2f$.

Comment: Please elaborate on the physics context of this question and how it differs from pure [mathematics.se]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That's not an ordinary derivative; it's a variational derivative. (In simpler notation):
$$
\left(\partial_{kk}\frac{\partial}{\partial f_{,kk}}-\partial_{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial f_{,k}}+\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\right)\left(-ff_{,kk}\right)=\partial_{kk}\left(-f\right)+\left(-f_{,kk}\right)=-f_{,kk}-f_{,kk}=-2f_{,kk}
$$

Comment: *it's a variational derivative* With the functional implied!

Comment: I think it's also called "functional derivative"... Correct me if I'm wrong, @G.Smith. Thing is... in physics rarely ever people consider higher than first-order Lagrangians, and are not aware of general definition... For general expression $f_{,ijk...}$ you have to include factorial denominators to correct for over-counting.

Comment: Yes. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative#Determining_functional_derivatives) has the general formula. But I don’t see the factorial denominators you mention. I think it’s hard for the OP to understand the negative sign in the second term unless they understand that it comes from integrating by parts in the (implied) functional integral.

Comment: One would if/when one had non-isotropic terms like $f_{,ijk}$. For indices that run from $1$ to $n$: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial f_{,i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{n}}}f_{,i_{1}i_{2}\cdots i_{n}}=\sum_{\pi\in S_{n}}\frac{\partial}{\partial f_{\pi\left(12\cdots n\right)}}f_{,\pi\left(12\cdots n\right)}=n!\frac{\partial}{\partial f_{,12\cdots n}}f_{,12\cdots n}$$. But it's not on Wikipedia, probably because we rarely ever consider those. Otherwise we would be overcounting $f_{123}$, $f_{231}$, etc.